# How to extract values from my state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I did a getAll call from my API and put all the values into this.state, but I don't know how to extract the arrays (or objects?) from my state. The information I want is the 'id' field from:

0: {id: 1, address: "1", workplace_count: 1, phoneline: "1", workplace_list: "1"}

1: {id: 40, address: "Address", workplace_count: 1, phoneline: "G", workplace_list: "G"}

This is what I see if I do console.log(this.state)

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, currentUser: {…}, users: null, workplaces: null, address: null, capacity: 0, …}
0: {id: 1, address: "1", workplace_count: 1, phoneline: "1", workplace_list: "1"}
1: {id: 40, address: "Address", workplace_count: 1, phoneline: "G", workplace_list: "G"}
address: null
capacity: 0
currentUser: {id: 1, firstName: "Admin", lastName: "User", username: "admin", password: null, …}
departments: null
fk_department: 1
id: 0
type: null
users: null
workplaces: null
__proto__: Object
```

I can get the other values, like for example capacity like this:
this.state.capacity

Filling up state method:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        userService.getAllDepartments().then(departments => {
            this.setState(departments)
            });
         }
```

Comment: Try `this.state[0].id`? It seems that `0` is a key in your `this.state` object.

Comment: @AnsonMiu tried that, doesn't work

Comment: How did you add the API data into your component state?

Comment: @AnsonMiu I edited my original post with the componentDidMount method which sets my state (for this relevant part at least)

Comment: I suggest to set state via `this.setState({ departments })` so you are adding the API result to a named property (“departments”) in the state object. This lets you access it via `this.state.departments` in a more convenient way.

Answer (score 1):

Try const {address}= this.state[0];

Answer (score 0):

Your state is an object which has keys `0` and `1`, which each have keys `id`. You should be able to access them via

```js
this.state["0"].id
this.state["1"].id
```

EDIT: Corrected to another way of accessing the 0 and 1-keys

Comment: this.state["1"]  works to get the whole object (array?), the .id part doesn't work though.

Comment: What do you get when you log `this.state["1"]` then?

Comment: I get the whole object: {id: 40, address: "Address", workplace_count: 1, phoneline: "G", workplace_list: "G"}

Comment: That sounds strange - you should be able to access the `id`-field from the object with the `.id` syntax. You can also try `this.state["1"]["id"]`, even though there shouldn't be a difference

Comment: I get an error both ways, this one :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Can it be because I'm doing it in render() and the first time it renders the values are undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the data you want from your state just applying the format `this.state.adress[0] and this state.adress[1]`